# htaccess force https + redirect to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My website (website.com) lies on directory : public_html/dirName/

I'm trying to :

redirect all traffic to *dirName* subdirectory without *dirName* appearing in the url

force https for domain

I figured out for first condition :

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dirName/.*$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dirName/$1 [L]`

And I found out this code for https :

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

But I can't figure out how to blend them together.

Right now, I have https://www.website.com working. But website.com, www.website.com or http://www.website.com redirect all to https://www.website.com/dirName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (blended version):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!dirName/).*)$ /dirName/$1 [L]
```

Because you should not redirect to www after redirecting to https (only one redirect). And even less redirect to `http://www` (and not https)

Comment: Thanks
It works perfectly
I wish I could upvote this

Answer (score 0):

I didn't blend them but it works this way :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dirName/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dirName/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As Croises said

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domainname.in%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

but I removed last line `RewriteRule ^((?!dirName/).*)$ /dirName/$1 [L]` => Give Internal Server Error. Now its working perfectly for me.